# How to scroll up/down through commands in vim without arrow keys

Tags: vim

I've disabled the arrow keys to practice using the various navigation commands. However, I'm not sure how to scroll up/down through multiple options or history items. A basic example would be:

```
:colors 256-grayvim
```

Usually, I can then press the up/down arrows to scroll through all the color options. Or, I commonly type `:` and then up/down to view my command history. Is there a better way to do this then without the arrow keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `<c-n>` and `<c-p>`. Those can navigate through your command history. To be honest i don't think that using the arrow keys is a bad option there. You should primarily avoid them in normal mode. 
See `:h up-down-motions`